# In Objective-C, is there a way to retrieve the subsystem and category of a os_log_t object after it has been created?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, logging

I am trying to learn `os_log_t` to use in my Objective-C Application for macOS. I create the os_log_t object like this:

```
static os_log_t _log = nil;

_log = os_log_create("com.alfonsotesauro", "base_connector");
```

I would like, at a later stage, to retrieve the subsystem and category used to create the log object at the beginning. I could find a hand-made solution like storing those values separately, but I would prefer an official way. Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: "retrieve the subsystem and category used to create the log object" You can't. It's sort of a semi object. It has no properties except its description.

Comment: If it is all you own code, you could wrap your own object around it which stores that info.